# Loading images not from "xampp's htdocs" or "root" folder

Tags: javascript, html

This is how the link looks like

```
<img src="http://127.0.0.1C:/Obrazy/Nowy%20obraz%20mapy%20bitowej.bmp" class="image-preview" style="width: 120px;">
```

This is the code that draws the link

```
 // images preview button
        if ($('table.file-list a[rel="lightbox[images]"]').length > 0) {
            $('a.view-style').show();
        } 

        $('a.view-style').click(function(){
            $('a.image-size').show('');
            $('a.view-style').remove();
            $('table.file-list a[rel="lightbox[images]"]').each(function(index) {
                var img_src = $(this).attr('href');
                $(this).prepend('<img src="'+img_src+'" class="image-preview">');

            });
        });
```

Is it possible to get the images from C:/Directory ? Its used on Windows 7. Need a fast solution/answer.

Comment: `<img src="http://127.0.0.1C:/Obrazy`... - are you sure this is not a typo?

Comment: yeah same here.. is that extar colon supposed to be there after 127.0.0.1C ?

Comment: This generates me this sec sadly is it possible to give a src to a hard drive not to htdocs/img or what ever?

Comment: You can't reference a file outside of the scope of webroot from within HTML. One method is to create a symlink in webroot pointing to the resource.

Comment: ChillNUT can u link me a to something like this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use file:/// before the image url path to be

file:///C:/Obrazy/Nowy%20obraz%20mapy%20bitowej.bmp

Comment: Possibly but var img_src = $(this).attr('href'); this generates me the http://127.0.0.1/imagename.extention  so its still the same this function needs be changed